# SwiftUI: first Button not tappable inside HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Going thru a very weird issue that looks like a bug to me.

Here's the code -

```
    HStack {
        
        Button(action: {
            print("DEBUG: follow pressed!")
        }, label: {
            Text("Follow")
                .frame(width: 180, height: 40)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        })
            .cornerRadius(20)
        
      
        Button(action: {
            print("DEBUG: message pressed!")
        }, label: {
            Text("Message")
                .frame(width: 180, height: 40)
                .background(Color.purple)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        })
            .cornerRadius(20)
        
    }
```

Code for entire view (might be useful) -

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileActionButtonView: View {
    let viewModel: ProfileViewModel
    @Binding var isFollowed: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.user.isCurrentUser {
            
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Text("Edit Profile")
                .frame(width: 360, height: 40)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        })
            .cornerRadius(20)
        } else {
            HStack {
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("DEBUG: follow pressed!")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Follow")
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                })
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                
              
                Button(action: {
                    print("DEBUG: message pressed!")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Message")
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.purple)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                })
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

What's weird?

If I switch the positions of both buttons in HStack, the first button (whichever is first) is always untappable. The second works just fine!

EDIT (adding image's code). Looks like the image (circular image of first tweet below the button) is overshadowing the follow button.

```
Image("batman")
                    .frame(width:  56, height: 56)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .cornerRadius(56/2)
                    .padding(.leading)
```

[image: Screenshot]

In the image - Follow button is untappable, Message button is tappable.

Comment: Copied the HStack and pasted it in a fresh new View right inside the body. Both buttons work :(
Cleaned build, Xcode restarted, device changed, nothing works

Comment: Same result here using the entire view and changing 'if viewModel.user.isCurrentUser {' to `if false {` as well as commenting the variables out. Worked fine. I would try it with a different simulator or an actual device.

Comment: after .cornerRadius(20) add this line   .zIndex(10)

Comment: @ikbal didn't work either, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Yrb you're right, looks like the issue is in the embedding of this whole view in another view. Independently in this view both buttons are clickable.

Comment: @Abbas - quick test, I created a new view, used a `VStack` with spacer, text, spacer, your `ProfileActionButtonView`, spacer, text, etc.... both buttons worked. Can you post the code for a View with this one embedded where the button *does not* work?

Comment: Yes, it works in all cases except the current arrangement in my project. I tried commenting things back and forth and found the exact component causing the issue. The strange part is the culprit is the circular image you can see in the tweets tabbar in the image. (the image that belongs to every tweet). Commenting it out or replacing it with another component makes the button clickable.

Comment: I think the first tweet's image is shadowing the first button (because it's so large) and have just clipped it to look small. Not sure, I'm very new to swift UI from flutter background. Adding my image's code in the question.

Comment: Sorted guys, added a .resizeable() to that image and buttons are clickable. The strange part (for me) is the image looked small because of .frame but it was actually taking a lot more space. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: It can happen depending how you change the size, but it is rare.  That would be another question with that code posted. It can be tough to reproduce with images as we don't necessarily have access to the one you are using.